# SharePoint Clear SPFieldChoice using Web Services

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint

I'm trying to clear the selection of a SPFieldChoice using Web Services. I'm currently creating a batch XML then using the UpdateListItems method while passing in an empty value.

This has not been updating the list however so I would appreciate any guidance.

The following is my web service call:

```
<Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1">
    <Method ID="1" Cmd="Update">
        <Field Name="ID">102</Field>
        <Field Name="Resolved_x0020_Status"></Field>
    </Method>
</Batch>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does the underlying field allow blank values?

Comment: Have you read the response to see if you are getting an error? There could be a totally seperate issue.

Comment: Hm... using the code you provide is working for me with a regular Dropdown single-select choice field. What type of choice field is it?